# Should I save any of my hunting spoils?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I've been slaughtering cute fuzzy wild animals for quite some time now, and my bag is chock full of bits of animal and wild herbs.

So far I've not found any crafting recipes or missions that require me to have any particular bits of stuff.  Further, all the challenges seem to want me to just kill or collect things, and aren't particularly concerned with the contents of my inventory.

Is there any of this which I need for any reason, or should I just sell it to make a quick buck?  (no pun intended...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are meant to be sold.

Although you'll meet random people out in the wild who want some hides, they'll just want to buy them from you.

However, if you complete the the Master Hunter and Survivalist [Ambient Challenges](http://www.ireddead.com/guide/reddeadredemption/ambient-challenges/) to Rank 10, you'll be able to make vittles out of animal meat and tonics out of plants, respectively.

- Vittles refill your health and is identical to the Medicine.
- Tonics refill your dead eye meter and is identical to the Chewing Tobacco.